# Jest mock can't return a closure

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm writing a simple app. I've used Jest to mock a local module to return fake data.

If I return the fake data in line everything works fine, for example.

```
jest.mock('./data/data', () => {
  return {
    <SAMPLE_DATA>
  };
});
```

However if I extract the sample data into a variable so I can later use the .toBe matcher like this

```
const mockData = {
  <SAMPLE_DATA>
};

jest.mock('./data/data', () => mockData);
```

I get the follwoing error

> ReferenceError: mockData is not defined

Both mockData and the call to jest.mock is at the top of the file after the import statements, and not inside any describe, it, beforeEach blocks.

I thought mockData would still be in scope because it is a closure. What am I doing wrong? Or do I have some missing knowledge around how closures work with Jest and JavaScript?

I'm using Node 10.19.0 and @testing-library/jest-dom version 4.2.4

Comment: jest.mock calls get hoisted to the top of the module (see e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#using-with-es-module-imports) so there's nothing to close over.

Comment: Given the mock is hoisted above the imports there is no way to pass the data into the mock. Not what I wanted to hear but thanks for the help. If you place your comment as the answer I will accept it